Error make file in qt5 template argument 159 is invalid make
qxkbcommon.cpp:276:16: error: ‘XKB_KEY_dead_lowline’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘XKB_KEY_dead_belowring’? 276 | Xkb2Qt<XKB_KEY_dead_lowline, Qt::Key_Dead_Lowline>, | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ | XKB_KEY_dead_belowring qxkbcommon.cpp:276:69: error: template argument 1 is invalid 276 | Xkb2Qt<XKB_KEY_dead_lowline, Qt::Key_Dead_Lowline>, | ^ qxkbcommon.cpp:277:16: error: ‘XKB_KEY_dead_aboveverticalline’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘XKB_KEY_dead_abovering’? 277 | Xkb2Qt<XKB_KEY_dead_aboveverticalline, Qt::Key_Dead_Aboveverticalline>, | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ | XKB_KEY_dead_abovering qxkbcommon.cpp:277:79: error: template argument 1 is invalid 277 | Xkb2Qt<XKB_KEY_dead_aboveverticalline, Qt::Key_Dead_Aboveverticalline>, | ^ qxkbcommon.cpp:278:16: error: ‘XKB_KEY_dead_belowverticalline’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘XKB_KEY_dead_belowtilde’? 278 | Xkb2Qt<XKB_KEY_dead_belowverticalline, Qt::Key_Dead_Belowverticalline>, | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ | XKB_KEY_dead_belowtilde qxkbcommon.cpp:278:79: error: template argument 1 is invalid 278 | Xkb2Qt<XKB_KEY_dead_belowverticalline, Qt::Key_Dead_Belowverticalline>, | ^ qxkbcommon.cpp:279:16: error: ‘XKB_KEY_dead_longsolidusoverlay’ was not declared in this scope 279 | Xkb2Qt<XKB_KEY_dead_longsolidusoverlay, Qt::Key_Dead_Longsolidusoverlay>, | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ qxkbcommon.cpp:279:80: error: template argument 1 is invalid 279 | Xkb2Qt<XKB_KEY_dead_longsolidusoverlay, Qt::Key_Dead_Longsolidusoverlay>, | ^ qxkbcommon.cpp:427:5: error: template argument 156 is invalid 427 | >::Data{} | ^ qxkbcommon.cpp:427:5: error: template argument 157 is invalid qxkbcommon.cpp:427:5: error: template argument 158 is invalid qxkbcommon.cpp:427:5: error: template argument 159 is invalid make[5]: *** [Makefile:811: .obj/qxkbcommon.o] Error 1
trying to compiling qt5
